# Mac OS X How to activate an external application that is already open?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I want to activate an external application.  I don't want to launch my application, because the application is already open. I only want to change the window to display that application.
Any ideas?

Comment: What sort of application?  A Cocoa app?  A Carbon app?  Something else?

Comment: the application can be "Preview", "Text Edit", "Microsoft Word"... all the file managers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`launchApplication`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method of NSWorkspace.
If the application is already opened, it will simply activate it:

```
[ [ NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace ] launchApplication: @"TextEdit.app" ];
```